# Hyperledger Fabric: data persistence between fabric-ca-server restart

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

What happens when a fabric-ca-server restarts? What about the data stored in fabric-ca-server.db - does that need to be backed up? And how do we provide that data to the fabric-ca-server again? And what about the certificates? Do we need to backup all certs and restart using the same certs or they won't match with data stored in genesis block? Could anyone explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any data in your database will be intact if you restart the fabric ca server, as long as you have not manually deleted any databases/tables.

To use the already existing database, give it the same connection string that your server was using before. The CA server will connect to whatever database your connection string is pointing to.

If you restart the CA server using a new signing key/cert, then all previously issued certificates will no longer pass authentication when trying to connect to the CA. If you want to all previously certificates to continue to work with the CA, you MUST use the same cert/key pair as before.

Comment: `MUST use the same cert/key pair` How we can achieve this?